# What should we do when encountering suspicious rep changes?

Tags: discussion, voting, serial-voting, voting-fraud

I stumbled upon this user who mysteriously got all their questions and answers upvoted in a single day:

[image]

What, if anything, should be done about that?

[image]

Comment: mod flag ...... (UPDATE: I did it for you)

Comment: If it is due to serial voting, then the system will pick it up, and do something with it. Of course, the person could have just been active that day. If the votes are all from the same (sock puppet) account, I suspect the system will have flagged it for further investigation.

Comment: Yeah, raise a mod flag. Even if it gets reversed by the system then we still have a case where at least two sock-puppets are voting. That needs to be stopped and accounts nuked. A mod is happy to pull that trigger ....

Comment: @TemaniAfif Just on any of the questions, right?

Comment: yes any post but be very detailed

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, I've handled it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I found [so](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10462954/maven97?tab=reputation) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10975673/janlan?tab=reputation) [more](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11330690/anupam-chaudhary?tab=reputation) [within](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10691560/thomas-so?tab=reputation) [minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9947147/ankur?tab=reputation) - should I raise a mod flag for all of them?

Comment: Just a note you need to _actually_ check the source, not the rep graph. Your _within_ got a 400 rep bounty, the other votes on it did get corrected. The issue is more when there's multiple socks, or where they repeat the voting after it is corrected

Comment: @Nick Check Dec 18 '19 for irregularities on *within* (:

Comment: I did, *"the other votes on it did get corrected.... The issue is more when ... they repeat the voting after it is corrected"*

Comment: @Nick So you think [this 240+ rep change](https://imgur.com/a/Rbm8g5f) out of which 70 got corrected is otherwise legitimate?

Comment: No, but the reversal _often_ misses stuff (I've got plenty of downvotes which were mass downvotes where not all were reverted), what's important is that they appear to have _learned_ from the mistake

Comment: @Nick ⠀⠀⠀O.o⠀⠀⠀

Comment: I think you should custom flag anything similar that you find suspicious.

Comment: Some user gain more than 2K reputation in a week. Posting users seems bit.. odd.

Comment: @Scratte Definitely. But if a user with 500 rep and 10 posts gets all 10 posts upvoted within minutes of each other I think suspicion is warranted, don't you think?

Comment: @leonheess Yes, that seems unlikely to happen naturally. But flagging it should be enough, no? I only questioned the need to post the links in a comment.

Comment: @Scratte Maybe it's just me but I am very hesitant to use the mod flags inflationary so I was reluctant the flag all of them. Robert Longson's comment curbed that reluctance and I did flag them. However, even though I contemplated deleting the comment, I ultimately decided against it out of contempt for these rep fraudsters. They brought any unwanted attention they might get from it on themselves.

Comment: @leonheess Not everyone that is serial upvoted did it to themselves. Some users get serial upvoted because some other user decides to reward them on all of their posts. How can you tell the difference from where you're at?  (I totally get the reluctance to flag though :-)

Comment: @Scratte Valid point. That is also why I omitted the user from the initial question. However, this comment will probably only be seen by the few people that stumble upon this comment section so I think it's okay.

Comment: @leonheess: yes, please flag any cases you think look like abnormal voting.